Unable to perform curd operation on Electron + Vite + React + Typeorm + Sqlite Application
I want to perform curd operation using sqlite but after creating connection getting N of issue if I resolve one then another issue will come please check in attachment. 
At the end Error: Could not resolve "@mongodb-js/zstd" imported by "mongodb". Is it installed? this issue will remain and not able to resolve.
I am proving github repo link where my code is written.
Using node 20.10.0
Goal to create Offline desktop application.
https://github.com/vijaysharma0757/electron-vite-react-sqlite-typeorm
